# Show that if $m,n$ are positive integers, then $1^m+2^m+\cdots+(n-2)^m+(n-1)^m$ is divisible by $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Show that if $m,n$ are positive integers *and $m$ is odd*, then $1^m+2^m+\cdots+(n-2)^m+(n-1)^m$ is divisible by $n$.
(Hint: Let $s=1^m+2^m+\cdots+(n-2)^m+(n-1)^m$. Obviously $s=(n-1)^m+(n-2)^m+\cdots+2^m+1^m$.
Consider these relations as equivalent ${}\bmod n$ and add them.)

$$1^m+2^m+\cdots+(n-2)^m+(n-1)^m=((n-1)^m+(n-2)^m+\cdots+2^m+1^m)\bmod n$$
$$(n-1)^m+(n-2)^m+\cdots+2^m+1^m=(1^m+2^m+\cdots+(n-2)^m+(n-1)^m)\bmod n$$
By adding them we get:
$$(1^m+(n-1)^m)+(2^m+(n-2)^m)+\cdots+((n-2)^m+2^m)+((n-1)^m+1^m)=((n-1)^m+1^m)+((n-2)^m+2^m)+\cdots+(2^m+(n-2)^m)+(1^m+(n-1)^m))\bmod n$$
That means that:
$$n|[(1^m+(n-1)^m)+(2^m+(n-2)^m)+\cdots+((n-2)^m+2^m)+((n-1)^m+1^m)]-[((n-1)^m+1^m)+((n-2)^m+2^m)+\cdots+(2^m+(n-2)^m)+(1^m+(n-1)^m))]$$
Or not?? 
And that is equal to $$n\mid 0$$
Is this correct? How can I continue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $m$ is odd, then $(n-i)^m +i^m \equiv (-1)^mi^m+i^m\equiv -i^m+i^m\equiv 0 \bmod n.$

Comment: I forgot the condition that $m$ is odd...I will edit my post...

Comment: So by adding $s+s$, we have a sum of $(n-i)^m+i^m$. So we get $2s=0\mod n \Rightarrow s=0\mod n$. Is this right?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then yes, $2s\equiv 0 \bmod n$ implies that $s\equiv 0 \bmod n$, but this is not true in general when $n$ is even.

Comment: And what is when $n$ is even? Is there an other way to solve this in this case? Or does the exercise not stand for even $n$'s?

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. Let $m=2$ and $n=3$. Then $3$ does not divide $1^2+2^2$.

Comment: In fact, all even $m$ does not work with $n = 3$.

Comment: I forgot the condition that $m$ is odd...I will edit my post...

Answer (score 1):

Still not true. If $m = 1, n = 2,$ then $1$ isn't divisible by $2.$ You need $n$ to be odd as well.

Comment: A ok...And if $n$ is also odd, is what I've done correct so far?

Comment: what you've done is equivalent to saying $n\mid 0,$ which is not really anything. see @Álvaro's hint.